# Add ng-if attribute dynamically in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using following directive for adding an attribute to HTML elements:

```
    module1.directive('rhVisibleFor', function ($rootScope) {
        return{
            priority: 10000,
            restrict: 'A',
            compile: function (el, attr) {
                el.removeAttr('rh-visible-for'); 
                el.attr('ng-if', '$layoutPreferences.visibilities[\''+attr.rhVisibleFor+'\']');
//                el.attr('ng-if', 'false');
                var fn = $compile(el);
                return function(scope){
                    fn(scope);
                };
            }

        }
    })
```

compilation executes successfully, but generated code does not responsive to changes. even if I explicitly set false for ng-if attribute it has been shown.

Comment: Please provide a plnkr or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

My problem resolved, the cause of problem was lack of `$scope` in directive dependencies

```
module1.directive('rhVisibleFor', function ($rootScope,$compile) ...
```